# Show selected row count in pagination in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-grid

I am using **ui-grid** in my project, I need to show the selected row index value in pagination part.

For example, there are total 100 items in my grid, it is divided into 4 pages, each page has 25 items. If I select 10th row from a page, I need show **10 of 25 items**

I am using :

**HTML**

```
 <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection > </div>
```

**controller:**

```
  $scope.gridOptions ={

  data:'data',
  coulmnDef: $scope.coulmnDef,
  paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75,100],
  paginationPageSize: 25,

};
```

could you please help me any one, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected rows by listening for `rowSelectionChanged` event, after which you can use the `getSelectedRows` method on `gridApi`'s `selection` object. To do so, add the following to your `gridOptions` object:

```
$scope.selection = [];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    modifierKeysToMultiSelect: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function () {
            $scope.selection = gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
        });
    }
};
```

Now everytime the selection changes, the `selection` array in your scope gets updated of which you can take the `length` property which gives you the selection count. Hope that helps, good luck!

Reference: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection

Comment: Hi @iH8, how to show in ui, actually i am not using external pagination, could you please help me out how can i do that, and i need show default pagination also. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry to say, as far as i know, there is no way to change the default pagination template used in the ` ui-grid-pagination` directive. Apart from making your own build of ui-grid. You'de need to use custom pagination. An example is given here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination

Comment: Okay Thank you so much @iH8